# Problem Facing while performing Interferometry using Sentinel-1 image

Tags: dem, remote-sensing, sentinel-1, sentinel-snap, insar

I am using sentinel 1 data to extract the surface elevation using snaphu-unwrap tool. I perform all the steps according to literature and all the steps provide data too. However in the last step where I do phase to elevation, everytime the elevation comes black as in no data is there. I don't know what is the problem but there is no outcome from the whole process.
the steps I followed

1. ‘S-1 Tops Split’
2. ‘Apply Orbit file’
3. ‘S1 TOPS Coregistration’ > ‘S1 Back Geocoding’
4. ‘S1 Enhanced Spectral Diversity’
5. ‘Interferogram Formation’
6. 'S1 tops deburst’
7. 'Goldstein Phase Filtering’
8. unwrap the phase:
   Snaphu Export
   ‘Snaphu unwrapping’
   snaphu import using the unphase image
9. phase to elevation

[the upper left image is phase image, the upper right is unphase image while the lower middle image is elevation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3gDG.png)

[The Process I follow is given in the link below as a pdf file.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1u8Vw3kAQiJ2Wyh-Dc22w9ZPHBBqMsE1l?usp=sharing)

Comment: which DEM is used for this last step? Could it be that it is not downloaded correctly and this causes the NoData result?

Comment: @AndyB I used SRTM 1Sec HGT (Autodownload), so I don't think it could be a problem here. BTW thank you.

Comment: Have you tried another for a test?

Comment: @AndyB yes, I have tried SRTM 3Sec Autodownload and even with the VH polarization. but the outcome is always same.

Comment: you used both polarizations for the process? I'd recommend to select VV directly at the beginning during TOPS Split. SNAP is easily confused here.

Comment: @AndyB I didn't use both at once. for the first three to four times, I tried with VV polarization. I used SRTM 1Sec HGT (Autodownload) first two times and SRTM 3Sec Autodownload last two times for VV polarization. however, when there was no outcome I used VH polarization for SRTM 1Sec HGT (Autodownload) once and then for SRTM 3Sec Autodownload the second time, but still there is no data or outcome.

Comment: Does Phase to Height result in an at least technically plausible result?

Comment: @AndyB Yes i did that too and there were result from it but it does to make any sense as the heights are shown to be more than thousand meters which highly differs with the ground data.

Comment: yes, Phase To Height is only relative and not linked to physical properties. Makes me wonder why Phase To Elevation won't work. Are you using the latest version of SNAP?

Comment: @AndyB I'm using 8.0 version of SNAP

Comment: As the problem is not replicable nor logical to me I'd suggest to update SNAP to the latest version and try again. 
The import after phase unwrapping was successful?

Comment: @AndyB it showed that it was successful

Comment: @AndyB I have updated SNAP but the result is still the same